# Getting the service after passing the connection to Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have been posting my issues around Dynamics 365 integration and I will briefly explain the issues I am facing.The code I am using to connect is this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<Password>", "<domain>"), Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.AuthenticationType.IFD, "<url>", "<port>", "<OrgName>");
    _orgService = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
            // Retrieve the version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
RetrieveVersionRequest versionRequest = new RetrieveVersionRequest();
    RetrieveVersionResponse versionResponse = (RetrieveVersionResponse)_orgService.Execute(versionRequest);
    Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Dynamics CRM version {0}.", versionResponse.Version);
```

The credentials wouldn't return the service request and this is the error log I receive.

```
Inner Exception Level 3 :
 Source  : System
 Method  : Receive
 Date    : 26/09/2018
 Time    : 11:19:51 AM
 Error   : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
 Stack Trace     : at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 
 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

 Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
 Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : OrganizationWebProxyClient is null
 Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : OrganizationServiceProxy is null
The application terminated with an error.
```

None of the sample programs from Microsoft that use a tooling connector wont work. I cannot use OrganizationClient connection as the integrations wont run using Microsoft.SDK.Client.dll. I am pretty stuck here and I wonder if it is an issue with the hosted CRM. Any help on this would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rarely needed to set the security protocol, so you could try skipping setting the security protocol and use a simple connection string in the `CrmServiceClient` constructor.

First, set the connection string according to your version:

On-premise IFD before CRM 2016:

```
var connectionString = "Url=https://contoso.litware.com; Username=someone@litware.com; Password=password; AuthType=IFD;"
```

On-premise IFD for CRM 2016 and later (v8.0+)

```
var connectionString = "ServiceUri=https://contoso.litware.com/contoso; Domain=contoso; Username=contoso\administrator; Password=password; AuthType=IFD; LoginPrompt=Never;"
```

Then pass it into the constructor:

```
var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Then you can check if the service is ready:

```
if(!svc.IsReady) { throw new Exception("Service not ready");}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include AuthType=Office365 in your connection string.

Replace line 2 of your code with this two lines below.
Where

- {url} is your D365 instance URL
- {username} is your D365 username (try: username or domain\username)
- {password} is your D365 password
- {hru} is your ADFS home realm url
- {domain} is your AD domain

  string conStr = $"AuthType=IFD;HomeRealmUri={hru};Domain={domain};Url={url};Username={username};Password={pass}";
  CrmServiceClient service = new CrmServiceClient(conStr);

Comment: Still no luck mate. The program just list servers in all continents and says everything returned null. I am wondering if I can use Office365 authentication as our connection works on IFD.

Comment: I have updated the connection string to reflect IFD parameters

Comment: Thanks but its the same error I am facing. To be honest the connection works fine with the Microsoft sample program using ToolingConnectorWPFClient but unfortunately that is not what i am looking for.